# Bash import or export variables

Tags: bash, import, terminal, export

I am adding commands into my bash profile and am trying to make my code simpler and want to delete the extraneous duplicated code. I have export statements and I have the commands running correctly but I am trying to simplify my code. I am using the same exact code for my commands and want to make it into one file. I am running the commands on a Mac terminal. I have installed npm, atom, atom shell commands and am on Mac OS version 10.14.5.

I tried changing the code structure around but I cannot figure out how to simplify and reuse the commands and make them into a function. The commands are duplicates of each other except that they are pointing to different file paths. I do not want to keep on reusing the same code and I am hoping to make it simpler but not sure how.

```
export snippet_project="/Users/kevinpleong/Desktop/my-programming-projects/snippet-creator-electronjs"

export programmingprojects="/Users/kevinpleong/Desktop/my-programming-projects"

export personal_website="/Users/kevinpleong/Desktop/my-programming-projects/personal-webiste"


edit-snippet-creator() {
  cd /Users/kevinpleong/Desktop/my-programming-projects/snippet-creator-electronjs
  atom .
}

edit-personal-website(){
  cd /Users/kevinpleong/Desktop/my-programming-projects/personal-website/
  atom .
}

edit-programming-projects(){
  cd /Users/kevinpleong/Desktop/my-programming-projects/
  atom .
}
```

I am hoping that it outputs the same thing as the bottom 3 blocks of code but I can simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified to this:

```
projects_directory="${HOME}/Desktop/my-programming-projects"

edit-snippet-creator() {
    atom "${projects_directory}/snippet-creator-electronjs"
}

edit-personal-website(){
    atom "${projects_directory}/personal-website"
}

edit-programming-projects(){
    atom "$projects_directory"
}
```

- The `export`s are redundant
- The variables are redundant since they would only each be used once. Only the projects directory is reused.
- Trailing slashes are unnecessary.
- [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

That said, as you get used to the shell I expect you'll want to move away from patterns like this, because they are a premature abstraction and they hinder you from learning all the powerful built-in features of the shell, such as <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion. For example, if you've already edited a project you can press <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> to search the command history for the name of that project. Also, I expect `atom`, like every sane shell command, can take a directory different from the current one as the target, so you can simply type `atom ~/Desktop/my`, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete `atom ~/Desktop/my-programming-projects/`, and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to see which projects are available.